# how to move from one app to another by implicit intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, intentfilter, android-implicit-intent

I'm new in android so please help me how to it.
im trying to do it by using custom intent filter.

Manifest file:

```
<activity android:name=".SecondActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="myaction"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

java code:

```
Intent intent=new Intent("myaction");
        startActivity(intent);
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
sendBroadcast(intent)
```

instead of

```
startActivity(intent)
```